# Copy files from Azure Blob Storage into azure SUSE LINUX VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I understand that we can mount Azure File shares onto Ubuntu Linux VM. Right now, is there any alternative to moving data into SUSE Linux VM instead of Ubuntu VMs?

moreover, my data lies on Blob containers instead of fileshare. if needed, i can move data into Fileshare from Blob containers. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: Not sure what, specifically, you're asking, and why it would make a difference using one distro over another. As far as moving data to a VM, there is a lot of documentation around the various APIs, SDKs, and command line tools specifically around blob-copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could mount Azure File shares onto Suse Linux VM**. You could use the following to mount your File shares.

> sudo zypper install samba*
>
> ##create your directory
>
> mkdir -p /home/test
>
> sudo mount -t cifs
> //shuitestdiag630.file.core.windows.net/shuifile [mount point] -o
> vers=3.0,username=shuitestdiag630,password=[storage account access
> key],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

More information please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux)

Also, you could download your blob data to your VM. You could use Azure CLI to manage your blob data. **Azure CLI supports to run on  Linux and download blobs.** More information about Azure CLI please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli)

Comment: Details you provided did are very useful.  Both the Samba server mount and Azure CLI worked on one of the HDInsight Cluster.

Comment: Details you provided turned out to be very useful.  Both the Samba server mount and Azure CLI worked on one of the HDInsight Cluster.                                                  Initially, I ignored the fact that both VM and Fileshares should be on same region. if both were hosted on two different region, mounting doesn't work. May be region specific constraint will be addressed sooner by Microsoft.  Thanks a lot for the tips. Much appreciated.

Comment: And how to move a blob file to file share? In my case I need to upload video to blob storage to streaming but also need to access this video files into my VM (same region) to edit, generate proxy and thumbnails using ``ffmpeg`` and for this I need the files accessible locally.